# pasting multiple times

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to copy something to your clipboard then past it X number of times? I need to paste some text I copied 295 times. I found a batch file that duplicates a file X number of times but I need to paste some raw text from my clipboard 295 times.

Comment: May be this link be a help http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3058

Comment: you should post the solution, it looks interesting

Comment: Why couldn't you paste to a new file, use the batch file you were talking about, then copy/paste the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many command line utilities that allow you to paste text from the clipboard, technically to write the clipboard text contents to `stdout`. You can find such a utility in Raymond Chen blog ***the new old thing*** http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/10/9919908.aspx

I use my own `CLIPTEXT` program. It is a very simple 5-lines pascal, here is the source code. I am sure that you can get the idea and translate it to any other language.

```
program cliptext;
uses clipbrd;
begin
  writeln(clipboard.asText);  
end.
```

then, in your batch files, you may use the text this way.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('cliptext') do set text="%%c"
for /L %%a in (1,1,295) do echo dosomething !text!
```